# Removing padded zeroes in Hexadecimal column

Tags: sql, t-sql, hex

I have a database in TSQL that contains columns in hexadecimal. However these values are padded with zeroes to fill the column.

I need to remove these zeroes just so I have the hexadecimal string. The problem is I cannot just remove pairs of zeroes as the string may have zeroes in the middle.

I have a feeling I need to convert it to say decimal and then back or something, but everything I try yields strange results.

The column in the database look like this:

```
1EBC67E6000000
6B1FE9C7830000
C700DBBF000000
```

The values are different lengths and all padded with pairs of zeroes.

Any ideas would be good!

Comment: It seems strange to pad the hexadecimal value with zeroes in the end. This makes the value change, if padding were in the beginning of the string instead the value remains the same. Compare 000111 and 111000 (decimal) the second one is not equal to 111.
How can you be sure that the value doesnt end with zeros?

Comment: Huh, that's tricky - if values have different lengths there's no way telling if it should be `C700DBBF` or `C700DBBF0`.

Comment: Are you looking to permanently remove these zeroes? If so what is the datatype of the column? If it is `binary` rather than `varbinary` these are there to pad the length and can't be removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will be good for you:

```
Select  replace(rtrim(replace('C700DBBF000000','0',' ')),' ','0');
```

Comment: it will remove zeros in the middle

Comment: no I replace 0 for space ' ' and I remove only this at the end. After that i replace spaces in the midle of string again to 0. Try this code in managment studio or in the database. It's good.

Comment: This does need you to convert the `varbinary` to a string representation first then back (code not supplied here!)