# SQL:Zero leading at insert into Image column

Tags: sql, sql-server, zero

I am trying to insert a HEX representation of XML (I get HEX string of xml file) into a `Image` column.

I tried this:

```
if exists (select [Version] from [...].[dbo].[Table] where Version ='1.1.1.1') 
   update [.....].[dbo].[Table] 
   set [Xsd] = 0xEFBBBF3C3F7857465466....
else 
   insert into [....].[dbo].[Table] ([Version], [Xsd]) 
   values ('1.1.1.1',0xEFBBBF3C3F7857465466....)
go
```

But, when I execute this query, I get first zero:

```
0x0EFBBBF3C3F7857465466.... - Image field, can NULL.
```

How to fix it? I [try to make replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429715/removing-padded-zeroes-in-hexadecimal-column) try to make replace:

```
Select  replace(rtrim(replace('0x0EFBBBF3C3F7857465466....','0',' ')),' ','0');
```

But get decimal-version: 307854...

And length is 217847 (I count from 0).

Another strings inserts without zero!

It seems that it is alignment at SQL Server: when I add 'E' symbol at the end of string- it makes a valid begin of string: 0xEFBB....

EDIT: i remove quotes ,but it does not works.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Why the INSERT statement have the HEX value between quotes? What is the data type of column Xsd? You are doing implicit castings there.

Comment: The type of [XSD] is Image,can be NULL

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a natural way to represent a set of bits that isn't divisible by 8 - if you ask it to store 12 bits (say, 0xABC) it will round that up and store those bits in two bytes. When you ask for those bits back, you'll find a `0` on the front for the extra four bits it had to store.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i fix this problem!

It seems that data corrupte when i copy\paste it from text editor;

So, i have to open my *.xml file from Hex editor (Hex Editor Neo), go-> 
View->Tool Windows->Copy&Export;

It will make window; At that window - select option - Without separators.-> it will make simple one-line string of file. So, copy all selected string- Press Copy and then Paste it into sql file.

You can use some other HEX-editor.